# How to quickly mock services in spring unit tests?

Tags: java, spring, junit

```
@Bean
public EntityManager(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
   //...
}
```

How can I quickly mock both of these beans (em + emf) inside a `JUnit` test?
Is there some framework that allows me to define eg `@Mock EntitiyManager em;`?

Comment: Have u seen Mockito and Powermock?

Comment: I think both require quite much configuration for each object that should be mocked. I'm rather looking for a framework that mocks the class by eg just applying a simple configuration statement or annotation on that class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [springockito](https://bitbucket.org/kubek2k/springockito/wiki/Home) together with [spring-test](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/testing.html). It integrates spring with mockito and supports both annotation based mocks and mocks configured in a spring applicationContext.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for: a simple `@ReplaceWithMock` to mock any service.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to be aware of the `@Mock` annotation, so presumably you know what Mockito is. You just mock the `EntityManager` exactly the same way you would mock anything else.

```
@Mock EntitiyManager em;
initMocks();
MyService myService = new MyServiceImpl(em);
```

Comment: Hi Steve, nice name, nice answer :)

Comment: Steve, don't you think that mocking of EntityManager is not the best way to write unit tests? It violates the well known "Don't mock what you don't own principle". I'd say it would be actually better to write a test with embedded Database and test real components instead of assuming what EntityManager would do and mocking/stubbing our expectations to it.

Comment: I do test with an in-memory database, but there are some things that are better tested using mocks. For instance, if I want to test whether a service method handles exceptions correctly from a call to `em.persist`, it's much more effective to do this by using a mock `EntityManager` to raise the exception and validate my handling of it.